# PHP displaying first letter of array in dropdown?

Tags: php, html

My issue is that the dropdown is actually populating correctly but with only the first letter of that particular line.

I have the following in my file:

Monday

Tuesday

Wed

It is displaying as:

M

T

W

Any ideas?

My code:

```
<select id="playlist_wrongstyle" class="form-control"  style="visibility:visible; width:250px;">
<option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
<?php
  $returnedScheduleNamesArray = explode ("\n", file_get_contents('/srv/http/schedulenames'));

  array_pop($returnedScheduleNamesArray); //remove empty last line

  foreach($returnedScheduleNamesArray as $name) 
  {
?>
      <option value="<?=$name['name']?>"><?=$name['name']?></option>
<?php
  }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Try just: `<?= $name ?>`

Comment: `$name` is a string?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Perfect! Thanks a million :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$name` is a string.  You should just echo name:  `<?= $name >`

The reason you are seeing a single letter:

- String characters can be accessed using array bracket syntax:

  ```
  $name = 'Monday';
  $name[0] === 'M'; // true
  ```
- PHP is coercing your string `'name'` into an integer, and this evaluates to `0`:

  ```
  (int)'name' === 0; // true
  ```
- So, `$name['any string'] === $name[0]; // true`

Answer (score 4):

This is basically what's happening with `$name['name']`:

```
foreach (['Monday', 'Tuesday'] as $name) {
    echo $name['nonexistent'];
}
```

If you adjust your error reporting level, you'll see

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'nonexistent'

When PHP sees you use `['something']` after a string, it thinks you're trying to access a specific character within it (which you *can* do, but only with numeric indexes). But, since PHP expects an integer there, when you reference an illegal string offset, it gets converted to an integer, so you'll *probably* get index zero, the first letter, unless your illegal string offset starts with something that will convert to nonzero. (e.g. `$day['3illegal']` gets you "d" and "s".)

Comment: Actually, you get index `0` because `(int)'some string'` evaluates to `0`

Comment: It's not just because PHP loves us? ;)

Comment: I guess it's a little bit of both. :)

Comment: You're right though, I probably shouldn't joke about such things. I'll edit.

Answer (score 3):

Ooops, you've found the PHP magic trick.  PRESTO! Strings are arrays!

```
         $name ='Bob';// thats a string
         echo $name['0']; // prints B, like an array
         echo $name['1']; // prints o, like an array
```

Strings variables are actually arrays, but in your case, you don't want that.. so

```
<option value="<?=$name?>"><?=$name?></option>
```

Comment: That'll print "o" - strings are zero-indexed just like arrays.

Comment: Well it was magic when I accidentally discovered it back in the year 2000sumthin , and I'll test but I thought they were zero index, eg;  $name['0'] was the whole string, 1 was the first char.. anyways, still magic, just unimpressive magic :p